# C++ inheritance - getClass() equivalent?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Take the following C++ for example.

```
vector<Animal> listAnimal;

class Fish : Animal ...
class Mammal : Animal ...
class Bird : Animal ...
```

If I then add them all to the list, and then grab them off the list arbitrary I wont know which subclass I am dealing with.  I in Java I could do `getClass()` or `thefish instanceof Fish`. How do I do this in C++?

Comment: Why do you need to know which? Generally, when storing a list like that, you'd call virtual functions on whatever's in there and the derivation would decide what it does.

Comment: I guess I don't need to I could just call doSomething() that they all implement from Animal.

Comment: Yes, if you're just calling functions like that on them and you want them to be dispatched for you, the answer below works. To dispatch them properly, you'd mark the function `virtual`, and optionally add an `= 0` at the end to make it pure, meaning the derivation must provide an implementation for it. Without being pure, if the derivation does not, it will use the base's implementation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You shouldn't need to know what type of sub-class you're dealing with. You're not doing polymorphism right if you need to check the type of class you're dealing with. The whole point of polymorphism is to reduce if's and make your code a lot more flexible.

There are some cases where you need to know, and you can use [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) for that. However I recommend not to, especially if you require a lot of performance (such as games or graphics programs).

Use the `typeid` operator to get information about a class, and to determine if a class is a specific type.

For example:

```
Animal* animal1 = new Cat;

if(typeid(animal1) == typeid(Cat))
{
     cout << "animal1 is a: " << typeid(Cat).name();
}
```

Then use a `static_cast` to cast it down the hierarchy.

```
Animal* animal1 = new Cat;

if(typeid(animal1) == typeid(Cat))
{
     Cat* cat = static_cast<Cat*>(animal1);
     cat->scratchTheLivingHellOutOfYou();
}
```

Alternatively you can use a `dynamic_cast` which is much safer, but much slower than a typeid/static_cast. Like so:

```
Animal* animal1 = new Cat;

if(Cat* cat = dynamic_cast<Cat*>(animal1)
{
     cat->scratchTheLivingHellOutOfYou();
}
```

### **EDIT:**

`dynamic_cast` is slower simply because it has to do a little extra work than just testing if it's a specific type and casting. i.e. `dyanmic_cast` is not equivalent to `typeid/static_cast`, but it almost is.

Imagine a hierarchy further than 2 levels deep, for example:

```
class Animal { /* ... */ }; // Base
class Cat : public Animal { /* ... */ }; // 2nd level
class Tiger : public Cat { /* ... */ }; // 3rd level
```

Let's say that in the Cat class, a method specific to all Cats is called: `scratchTheLivingHellOutOfYou()`. Let's also say that: I have a list of Animals and I want to call `scratchTheLivingHellOutOfYou()` for every Cat in the list (this includes classes that derive from the class Cat). If the `typeid` operator and `static_cast` is used, this  would not achieve what is required, since `typeid` only checks for the current type and does not care about the hierarchy. For this, you have to use a `dynamic_cast`, since it will check if a class is derived from a base-class, and then cast up/down the hierarchy accordingly.

You can see this simple example, in C++, [here](http://ideone.com/4annRR). Here is the output of the program:

```
USING TYPEID


*scratch*
meoyawnn!
RAWR



USING DYNAMIC_CAST


*scratch*
meoyawnn!
*scratch*
RAWR
```

Therefore, you can clearly see that `dynamic_cast` does a lot more work than a simple `typeid` and `static_cast`. Since `dynamic_cast` looks up the hierarchy to see *if* it is a specific type. Simply put... `dynamic_cast` can cast up *and* down the hierarchy. Whereas a `typeid` and `static_cast` can only cast down the hierarchy to a specific type.

I thought I'd mention that if `dynamic_cast` fails it will return a NULL pointer, or throw an exception if you're using it with references.

### **NOTES:**

1. If you really need performance and you need to check types of polymorphic objects, I recommend finding an alternative to RTTI, such as using templates/macros or whatever else to identify classes.
2. `dynamic_cast` should only be used if you're not sure the object will be the type you're converting to. If you, as a programmer, know whatever you're casting is 100% going to be that type then use `static_cast`, e.g. if you know animal1 is *going* to be a `Cat` then `static_cast` is more appropriate.

Comment: Why is dynamic_cast slower?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain See the Edit I made in the post.

Comment: You're missing the `*` from `dynamic_cast<Cat*>(animal1)`.

Comment: @aschepler Whoops, my bad.

Comment: However, I've tried this with `static_cast` and it works identically to `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: @Belov see my second note. tl;dr if you know the object is going to be the type you're casting to, use `static_cast`.

Answer (score 2):

A container only stores elements of a fixed type, you want a pointer to an object.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>> animal_list;

animal_list.emplace_back(new Fish);
animal_list.emplace_back(new Mammal);
animal_list.emplace_back(new Bird );
```

Store `Animal` type in vector will cause `object slice` when push derived types into listAnimal.

```
 vector<Animal> listAnimal;
 listAnimal.push_back(Fish);  // Fish is sliced to Animal, no fish for you.
```

Edit:

To know what type a derived animal is, you could store it in a member

```
Enum AnimalType
{
  FISH,
  MAMAL,
  BIRD
};

class Animal
{
public:
  Animal(AnimalType animal_type) : type(animal_type) {}
  AnimalType GetType() const { return type; }
private:
  AnimalType type;   
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was a little hap hazard when I wrote the code in the question in my program they are pointers to an Event class.

Answer (score -1):

I typically create a pure virtual function that each derived class implements to tell you its identity. Example:

```
enum AnimalType
{
   Fish = 0,
   Mammal,
   Bird
}

class Animal
{
   virtual AnimalType GetType() const = 0;
}

...

AnimalType Bird::GetType()
{
   return Bird;
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
if (animal.GetType() == Bird)
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted?  What's so bad about this approach?