# What does getClass() in Java actually return?

Tags: java, c++

I am a C++ programmer currently picking up Java. I'm having trouble with digesting the getClass() method in Java, and I would greatly appreciate any insights you may have to offer. From my understanding, [C++'s dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14531978/4849051) and Java's getClass() are loosely related in the sense that they are different means to the same end. In C++, I could use dynamic_cast to determine polymorphic types, whereas in Java, I could use getClass() to determine an object's most derived class type.  With a dynamic_cast, I can get back a pointer; with getClass(), I get back a class, but what does that return type (class) *actually* represent? Is it a pointer to the class?

Comment: C++ doesn't have reflection to speak of; Java does. `getClass()` is the entry point into Java reflection machinery. C++ doesn't have anything comparable; `dynamic_cast` is only a pale shade.

Comment: its simply an object which represents all the properties of the class. it's name, package etc and this is the object you can use to get references to members, methods etc for reflection. but ultimately it's a "value object" which tells you about the class, but there no direct correlation and reference /pointer level.

Comment: It's necessarily an object that represents the class. In a practical sense it is a run-time embodiment of the class, since it supports instantiation (a `newInstance` method).

Comment: `getClass()` returns the java.lang.Class object that represents the source object's class.  You may use the methods of Class on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From my understanding, C++'s `dynamic_cast` and Java's `getClass()` are loosely related

C++ [`typeid` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) would provide for better comparison. The major difference is that in C++ `typeid` requires a class to have at least one virtual function, while `getClass` in Java can be called on objects of any type without restrictions.

> what does that return type (class) actually represent?

It represents a [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object suitable for doing *reflection* on the class - something that has no direct counterpart in C++. For example, you can determine all interfaces the class implements, the base class of the class, list all methods, list all fields, call methods by name, and so on.

Comment: So getClass() actually returns an object that holds a memory address? Would that object inherit the source object's fields and methods?

Comment: @TimothyTse `getClass` returns an object that is common for all objects of your object's class. For example, if two objects are `String x = "x", y="y"`, calling `x.getClass()` and `y.getClass()` would return the same `Class` object. Moreover, that would be the same object returned by `String.class` operator.

Comment: @TimothyTse `Class` object does not "inherit" anything from actual objects. `Class` objects are prepared by the compiler; they have lists that describe fields and methods of your class.

Comment: Ah, so would it be accurate to say that the `Class` object is allocated at compile-time and has some sort of a data structure that "describes" the fields and methods of the class? May I ask how it actually describe the fields and methods?

Comment: @TimothyTse It's not accurate to say that anything is allocated at compile time because allocation is strictly a runtime thing, but the data for the `Class` objects becomes fully prepared at compile time, so what's left to do at run time is to allocate space for it and copy prepared metadata into that space. As far as the way the `Class` describes your object goes, the best way to learn this would be working through Oracle's [tutorial on Java reflection APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).